# How to scroll to the bottom in FlashList component? React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to scroll to the bottom in FlashList component? React Native? For example when screen opens it automaticity reach to end of the List?

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlashList} from '@shopify/flash-list';

const MyComponent = ({route}) => {

   const { chat } = route.params;

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={chat}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to automatically scroll to the bottom of your FlatList in React Native when your screen opens, you could use a combination of the ref prop and the scrollToEnd method.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = ({route}) => {
  const { chat } = route.params;

  const flatListRef = useRef();

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    // Your component for rendering each item
  );

  const keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chat && flatListRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd();
      }, 0); 
    }
  }, [chat]); // Listen for changes in the `chat` data

  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={flatListRef}
      data={chat}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks,This works but what you used setTimeout?

Comment: setTimeout is used to ensure the list gets scrolled to the end after it is fully rendered.

Comment: But in my case chat also take time to fetch to what should i do? because of that i also get this error " ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined]"

Comment: This can be a solution but it give the same error useEffect(() => {
    if (chat) {
      flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd();
    }
  }, [chat]);

Comment: i see but still it gives that same error in order to fix that error i need to edit the set timeout value of 3 secs any other approach in your mind?